# .NET double format string: how do I get full decimals as well as thousand separator?

Tags: .net, string, format-string

I have a `Double` value and need to find the format string, which converts this value with however many decimals the double value has, as well as with thousand separator.

For example, let's say I have value 1000000.1256. If I don't use any format string, then the default string has full decimals (four digits) but doesn't have thousand separator (`1000000.1256`). If I use the standard format string "N", then the output is `1,000,000.13`, i.e., it uses 2 decimals by default and does the rounding. But I don't want it to perform ANY rounding, I want to display `1,000,000.1256`. And please note that I don't know how many decimals the number has, that's why I said I want to display "full" decimals, instead of 2, or 4, or any other larger number of decimals. I know I can do it like this with customize string: "#,#.##########" so it displays up to 10 decimals and it is very unlikely that my numbers have more than 10 decimals. But is this the only/best way?

Comment: Do you understand that you won't have an exact value of 1000000.1256 in a `double`? You almost certainly don't want the *precise* value represented in the `double`... Perhaps you should be using `decimal`?

Comment: @JonSkeet You mean because there might be small difference between the decimal form and the binary form of a number, there is no way to display "full" decimal part without specifying the decimal number, right? So I have to use something like #,#.########## and as long as the decimal number of my number don't exceed 10 it should be OK and it is the only way.

Comment: Yes, my point is that there may be no difference in representation between 1000000.1256 and 1000000.1256000001, so you can't really say you want the "full" decimal representation. Again, I think `decimal` would be a better option for you.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your reply. Yes `Decimal` seems to be a better solution (we are displaying financial figures) but since the library has been existing and using `Double` for ages, for most of the values, I should just live with it.

Comment: In that case, I think you're in a difficult place - you claim you don't want it to perform any rounding, but 1000000.1256 *would* be a rounded value.

Comment: @JonSkeet Since this UI app I am working on is for individual financial trades, so for example if the user makes a Japanese Yan trade with 1000000000.12345, which has 15 decimals (the limit of `Double` value) it is the exact number but if the value is 1000000000.123456 then it performs rounding (it displays 1,000,000,000.12346). But I guess "1 billion point 123456" is one of the most extreme values that we encounter. And 15 decimals should be enough (it has been working in our legacy software).

Comment: Well, just because `double` is limited to be *accurate* to 15 decimal places, that doesn't mean that the exact value only has 15 decimal places. It can easily have more - you can use my [`DoubleConverter`](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) class to see the real exact value.

Comment: @JonSkeet I see your point. And I forgot to mention my work is a `TextBox` which accepts user-input double value (and then using a `Converter` to format the input data so it is more friendly-readable. So I am asking for the `FormatString` of this `Converter`). So when I say 15 decimals is enough, I mean it is most definitely the user will not input a number which is longer than 15 decimals. So in that case I guess the converted value is the exact value as input

Comment: Okay, in that case you have somewhat strange requirements, but your custom format string looks like it's probably the best way forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notion of "full decimals" is nonsensical.  How many full decimals does 10.0 / 3.0 have?  There are an infinite number of numbers that are *rational* but not "perfect".  A computer will make it significantly worse, it does math with two fingers instead of ten, turning values like 0.1 into a number with an infinite number of digits.

You are converting numbers to strings for the benefit of a *human*.  Humans are **not** interested in strings with an infinite number of digits, they tend to tune out after 7.  Displaying more than 15 when the variable is of type *double* is never useful, any digits beyond the 15th are random noise.  An inevitable side-effect of computers not having storage for an infinite number of digits.

Create a usable user interface first.  If you don't know what is considered "usable" then you have to ask your customers.  They *do* have rules about that in the financial industry, you can't just make up your own.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I see your point. I thought I could have a string format which doesn't need to specify the number of decimals (which I thought was an unwanted restriction) for the user-input value. But clearly that can't be done and shouldn't. Because theoretically nothing forbids the user to input a value which has decimals longer than 15.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do extra string operations I believe. It's not a elegant way maybe, but still I think it gives what you need.

```
        double number = 1000000.1256;

        string numberStr = number.ToString();
        string[] arr = numberStr.Split(',');//my cultureInfo is Turkish so I used ','

        string result = Int64.Parse(arr[0]).ToString("0,00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "." + arr[1];
```

result: 1,000,000.1256